# How to show the content of each Evernote note in Django

Tags: python, django, evernote

https://github.com/evernote/evernote-sdk-python/blob/master/sample/django/evernote_oauth_sample/templates/oauth/callback.html

https://github.com/evernote/evernote-sdk-python/blob/master/sample/django/oauth/views.py

show the content of the 1st note (works):

// views.py (my fork)

```
updated_filter = NoteFilter(order=NoteSortOrder.UPDATED)
updated_filter.notebookGuid = notebooks[0].guid
offset = 0
max_notes = 1000
result_spec = NotesMetadataResultSpec(includeTitle=True)
result_list = note_store.findNotesMetadata(auth_token, updated_filter, offset, max_notes, result_spec)

note_guid = result_list.notes[0].guid
content = note_store.getNoteContent(auth_token, note_store.getNote(note_guid, True, False, False, False).guid)
return render_to_response('oauth/callback.html', {'notebooks': notebooks, 'result_list': result_list, 'content': content})
```

---

// oauth/callback.html (my fork)

```
<ul>
  {% for note in result_list.notes %}
    <li><b>{{ note.title }}</b><br>{{ content }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
```

**How to show the content of each note in Django ?** *(this is one of unsuccessful attempts)*

```
updated_filter = NoteFilter(order=NoteSortOrder.UPDATED)
    updated_filter.notebookGuid = notebooks[0].guid
    offset = 0
    max_notes = 1000
    result_spec = NotesMetadataResultSpec(includeTitle=True)
    result_list = note_store.findNotesMetadata(auth_token, updated_filter, offset, max_notes, result_spec)

    contents = []
    for note in result_list.notes:
        content = note_store.getNoteContent(auth_token, note_store.getNote(note.guid, True, False, False, False).guid)
        contents.append(content)

return render_to_response('oauth/callback.html', {'notebooks': notebooks, 'result_list': result_list, 'contents': contents})
```

---

```
<ul>
  {% for note in result_list.notes %}
      {% for content in contents %}
        <li><b>{{ note.title }}</b><br>{{ content }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should associate your content with each note using some data structure(assume that no `note.title` are the same):

```
title_contents = {}
for note in result_list.notes:
    content = note_store.getNoteContent(auth_token, 
                                        note_store.getNote(note.guid, 
                                        True,False, False, False).guid)
    title_contents[note.title] = content

return render_to_response('oauth/callback.html', {'notebooks': notebooks, 
                                                  'result_list': result_list, 
                                                  'title_contents': title_contents})
```

In your template:

```
<ul>
  {% for title, content in title_contents.items %}
    <li><b>{{ title }}</b><br>{{ content }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: `{% for title, content in title_contents.items %}`
fixed variable name, title_contents instead tield_contents

Comment: Shang Wang, Thank you for a great help!

Comment: The one thing I'd add: assuming that titles are unique is a bit dangerous, you should use note guids instead. guid_contents = {}, guid_contents[note.guid] = contents